# Length of the resulting DataFrame slice is greater than the length of the labels-list provided in the argument of the .loc[] attribute

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to obtain a slice of a DataFrame using the .loc[] attribute. I provided a list of labels in the argument. But, I don't understand why the length of the DataFrame slice is greater than than the length of the list provided in the argument. In the following code, 'get_list_of_university_towns()' and 'convert_housing_data_to_quarters()' are two pre-defined functions which returned two different DataFrames.

```
utowns = get_list_of_university_towns().set_index(['State','RegionName']).index
alltowns_data = convert_housing_data_to_quarters()
X = alltowns_data.loc[utowns]
utowns_set = set(utowns)
non_utowns = [item for item in alltowns_data.index if(item not in utowns_set)]
len(non_utowns)
Y = alltowns_data.loc[non_utowns]
len(Y)
```

Here, I get the length of the non_utowns list as 10,461 and the length of the DataFrame slice to be 10,937.

Answer (score 0):

Happens if there are duplicates in the index. A minimal example below:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5),columns=list("abcde"),index=["a1","a1","a2","a3","a4"])

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
           a         b         c         d         e
a1  0.127354 -0.629876 -0.632672  0.724379 -0.229413
a1 -0.460529  1.109605 -0.515612  1.351368 -0.458339
a2  0.803422  0.679793  1.294371  0.894829  0.035137
a3  1.413082 -0.893431 -2.041129  1.498739  0.021033
a4  1.233385 -0.829729  0.446116  1.665736 -0.309078

In [7]: nu = [x for x in df.index if x[-1] != "2"]

In [8]: nu
Out[8]: ['a1', 'a1', 'a3', 'a4']

In [9]: len(nu)
Out[9]: 4

In [10]: df.loc[nu]
Out[10]:
           a         b         c         d         e
a1  0.127354 -0.629876 -0.632672  0.724379 -0.229413
a1 -0.460529  1.109605 -0.515612  1.351368 -0.458339
a1  0.127354 -0.629876 -0.632672  0.724379 -0.229413
a1 -0.460529  1.109605 -0.515612  1.351368 -0.458339
a3  1.413082 -0.893431 -2.041129  1.498739  0.021033
a4  1.233385 -0.829729  0.446116  1.665736 -0.309078

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
           a         b         c         d         e
a1  0.127354 -0.629876 -0.632672  0.724379 -0.229413
a1 -0.460529  1.109605 -0.515612  1.351368 -0.458339
a2  0.803422  0.679793  1.294371  0.894829  0.035137
a3  1.413082 -0.893431 -2.041129  1.498739  0.021033
a4  1.233385 -0.829729  0.446116  1.665736 -0.309078
```